# I want to send posts with captcha validation in flask, but when sending, the captcha is reloaded and does not match the one entered in the form

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, captcha

To put it simply: I have code that sends and saves posts using flask and I have code that generates a captcha. Both work separately, I don't know how to make them work together.

Code from [flask tutorial:](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/blog/)

```
@bp.route("/create", methods=("GET", "POST"))
@auth.login_required
def create():
    """Create a new post for the current user."""

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        title = flask.request.form["title"]
        body = flask.request.form["body"]
        capcha_value = captcha.get_captcha()
        user_captcha = flask.request.form["captcha"]
        error = None
        print('user_captcha:', user_captcha)
        print('capcha_value:', capcha_value)

        if user_captcha != capcha_value:
            error = 'Wrong captcha, try again.'  # This error every time.

        if error is not None:
            flask.flash(error)
        else:
            database = db.get_db()
            database.execute(
                "INSERT INTO post (title, body, author_id)"
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                (title, body, flask.g.user["u_id"]))
            database.commit()
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for("blog.index"))

    return flask.render_template("blog/create.html")
```

Form:

```
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='captcha.gif') }}"></a>
    </div>
    <input name="captcha" id="captcha" value="{{ request.form['captcha'] }}" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

Captcha code:

```
import random

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def get_captcha():
    my_captcha = Captcha()
    capcha_value = my_captcha.make_captcha()
    return capcha_value
    
class Captcha:
    population = 'abcdefghi0123456789jklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    save_folder = __file__.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/static/'

    def __init__(self, img_length=90, img_width=60, max_symb_length=8):
        self.img_length = img_length
        self.img_width = img_width
        self.max_symb_length = max_symb_length

    def make_captcha(self):
        k = random.randint(3, self.max_symb_length)
        random_string = ''.join(random.choices(self.population, k=k))
        img = Image.new('RGBA', (self.img_length, self.img_width), (0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        draw.text(
            (random.randint(0, self.img_length - self.max_symb_length*6),
             random.randint(0, self.img_width - 10)),
            random_string, fill=(38, 38, 38)
            )
        rand_l = lambda: (
            random.randint(0, self.img_length),random.randint(0,self.img_width)
            )
        for i in range(0, random.randint(3, 6)):
            draw.line((rand_l(), rand_l()), fill=(38, 38, 38),
                      width=random.randint(0, 2))
        for i in range(0, random.randint(5, 15)):
            draw.point((rand_l(), rand_l(), rand_l(), rand_l(), rand_l()),
                       fill=(38, 38, 38))
        img.save(self.save_folder + 'captcha.gif', 'GIF', transparency=0)
        return random_string
```

Was trying to put capcha_value = captcha.get_captcha() before if flask.request.method == "POST": and captcha image in form out of post form, but it was no effect. Don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/flask-session-captcha/

i had also same problem then i use this option its better for captcha validation actually

first install the package and then import to your code
this codes you need to add it in your app.py file

```
# import the package
from flask_session_captcha import FlaskSessionCaptcha

#config with your flask app
app.config["CAPTCHA_ENABLE"] = True
app.config["CAPTCHA_LENGTH"] = 5
app.config["CAPTCHA_WIDTH"] = 160
app.config["CAPTCHA_HEIGHT"] = 60
app.config["CAPTCHA_SESSION_KEY"] = 'captcha_image'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = conn

captcha = FlaskSessionCaptcha(app)

#add this line to your main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel("DEBUG")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5050, debug=True)
```

Here's the front code code from login.html

```
<form action="login" method="post">
<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" style="width:400px;" required>
<br>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" style="width:400px;" required>
<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" style="width: 400px;">
<br>
   {{ captcha(css_class="captcha") }}
<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="LOGIN">
```

it will definitely sort out your problem you dont need validate youreself this package will help you